# OrchardCMS is blocking Anonymous Users when accessed remotely

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, configuration, permissions, orchardcms

I have a production OrchardCMS site that is running fine.

Today I copied all of the files from that site to a local server so I could use it for staging and testing changes before deployment.  One other little change I made is changed the Orchard instance to use a local full SQL instance instead of Sql CE.  (Which is something I will also do in production in the next few days.)

The migration has worked fine.  I can load the Orchard instance using localhost on port 2764 (the one I assigned) and it works perfectly ... exactly as on production.

I setup port forwarding on my router to connect to this staging/testing server when connecting on port 2764.  (And also created an inbound rule on the local server).

When I access the site on that port from a remote computer, it loads the CONTENT but does not fetch any of the files (CSS, JS, etc.) So I see content but it is raw unformatted html.

I loaded the page in fiddler and it shows a header like this for the sessions...

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /Users/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2fThemes%2fBootstrap%2fStyles%2fbootstrap.min.css
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 03 Dec 2012 04:38:01 GMT
Content-Length: 205
```

and then ...

```
GET /Users/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2fThemes%2fBootstrap%2fStyles%2fbootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: -1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 03 Dec 2012 04:38:01 GMT
Content-Length: 2179
```

If I login to the site (I can still see the login button and subsequent login page) I am successfully logged in and then the website performs perfectly normally...until I log out again.

So the bottom line...anonymous users can see content but OrchardCMS (or IIS ... or both?) will not fetch any of the files it seems.

Any ideas on the cause of this?  Thanks for your help.

Seth

Comment: First place I'd look at is web.config. The one in Orchard.Web and the one in the directory where the non-loading files are.

Comment: It looks like web.config files in Scripts, Styles and/or other folders with static files that are being loaded are either missing or invalid.

Comment: Can you tell me in what way they should be invalid?  What entries would allow these items to load.

Comment: And how come it works on my production server?  Same files.  Is it an NTFS permissions issue?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was a straight up NTFS permissions thing.  Anonymous Users were using the IUSR identity which I had not given any permissions.  I changed that to use the APP POOL identity and all has been well.  I suppose I could also have given read permissions to IUSR.